# How to interrupt infinite loop in Prolog

Tags: infinite-loop, interrupt, swi-prolog

I entered infinite loop in Prolog with trace on. How can I interrupt it without closing Prolog?
`break` does something, but not full interruption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the menu bar you can go to Run -> Interrupt

Answer (score 2):

You can also press Ctrl+C which will show you this:

```
Action (h for help) ?
```

You type "a" (for abort) and then press enter.